# Quickest navigation within a buffer

Tags: cursor-movement

Okay, here's the thing: let's say you have a buffer, 1000 lines long (a source code for example). And you want a super-fast navigation, jumping to the right place. Example:

You are on a line 42, on character 44 (quotation after exclamation mark). You would like to access line 20, character 34 (`w` of `which_has`):

```
20    def very_interesting_function(which_has, some_interesting, arguments):
...
42         s = "I want to master the universe!"
```

What's the quickest way to get there? Plugins, custom keybinds are welcome!

My solutions:

1. `?whichi`
2. `22k%a` -- requires simple math
3. `20ggf(a`
4. hold `k` and then `f(a` -- takes too long
5. hold `{` or `(`, then `j` or `k` if needed, `f(a` -- too lame

But this is just an easy example. The use case may be far more complicated -- getting to a position of the screen, where 2) and 3) are unfeasible.

So, what you guys use? I feel like searching (`/`, `?`) is most superior.

Edit: looks like my question may be a dupe of [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/528/move-vertically-to-a-specific-character-on-a-different-line). The main difference is that [Peter](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/778/peter-rincker) provided very precise answer (I couldn't find such an excellent answer in the former question).

Comment: This seems very opinion-based ... You're not really asking anything, except "which of these 3 solutions is considered the best" (since the last 2 are considered too "long" or "lame")...

Comment: My point really is: is there a best practice (or a plugin) for precise vertical movement? Horizontal movement is pretty easy: `f`, `t`

Comment: "So, what do you guys use?" is more of a poll than a real question.

Comment: What do you mean by "precise vertical movement"? You're describing moving to a different column as well as a different row; that's not precisely "vertical." It sounds like you're just asking "how do I perform an arbitrary movement in Vim" without noticing that (to give an off-the-cuff estimate) 90% of Vim keystrokes are movement-related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So many options besides the ones you provided:

- If you know the line number then use `G` with a count or just a range to jump to the line. e.g. `20G` or `:20`
- Turn on `'relativenumber'` via `:set relativenumber` to make short jumps easier
- Jump to the start of previous method definition via `[m`. (`[m` can take a count as well)
- Use `[[` or `]]` to move to the previous or next section respectively (usually function definitions).
- If the word is somewhere else near the cursor then do `#`/`*` and spam `n` till you get there. (`n` can take a count)
- Use `H` (high), `M` (middle), or `L` (low) to jump to screen positions to shorten the distance.
- Possibly use `gd` (go-to-definition) if you are on the word
- If you use ctags then use commands such as `<c-]>` or `:tag`
- Maybe use `:cscope`
- `:vimgrep/which_has/ %` and use the quickfix list commands like `:cn` or `:copen` (good for very large jumps)
- Use a plugin like [easymotion](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion) or [sneak.vim](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak)

Personally each situation calls for something different but it's hard to go wrong with searching with `/`.

For more help see:

```
:h G
:h :[range]
:h 'rnu'
:h [[
:h [m
:h H
:h gd
:h ctags
:h :vimgrep
:h c_%
:h quickfix
:h :cn
:h :copen
:h /
:h quickref
```

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping for. Thank you!