# Vertical Navigation secrets without a plugin

Tags: normal-mode

At my workplace using my current compiler I have a vim plugin enabled.
The only thing that I am uncomfortable with vim is vertical line navigation and I wanted to know how some of the vim gurus overcome this situation.My typical work scenario would be a situation such as this:

Suppose I am on a page displaying lines 145 till 220. My cursor is on line 150 and I would like to go to line 183. To do so I would type `183G`.

I wanted to know if there was an easier way to accomplish that(because sometimes a line number might be in the thousands). What techniques do people here use for vertical navigation ? In this case it seems to be easier if I just grabbed the mouse and moved there instead. Any advice on this situation would be helpful.

Comment: This recent question may be helpful: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7323/hardcore-vim-mode-what-is-the-best-way-to-move-vertically

Comment: Enable *relative* line numbers and move using `count` `j`/`k`.

Comment: Similar posts: [Hardcore vim mode: what is the best way to move vertically?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7323/778) or [Quickest navigation within a buffer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2230/778)

Comment: You might consider looking at `:help z`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different way to move vertically in Vim, they all depends on what you want to do:

- In normal mode <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd> allows to move to the beginning or the end of a paragraph (i.e. a block of lines without blank or empty line)
- In normal mode <kbd>Shift-h</kbd>, <kbd>Shift-m</kbd> and <kbd>Shift-l</kbd> allows you to go the the top, the middle and the bottom of the screen.
- You can use `/pattern` to search for the next occurrence of a desired pattern and use `?pattern` to make a backward search. Use <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>Shift-N</kbd> to repeat the search in the same way or in the contrary way. To use this method you might want to add `set incsearch` to your `.vimrc` to see the pattern matched as you type it.
- Another solution is to use marks: if you know a place where you regularly need to go in your file you can set a mark at this line with <kbd>m-[X]</kbd> where `[X]` is one of the letters of the alphabet. You can then use <kbd>'-[X]</kbd> anywhere in the file to go back to this line.
- Finally if you are editing source code files you can use a tag system (like [exuberant-ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) ) combined with the [taglist plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/taglist.vim) to navigate your code.

Use the corresponding method depending on how "fast" you need to navigate.

Comment: Point 3 is very similar to Bram's document, http://www.moolenaar.net/habits.html (see part 1 about file navigation). There is the mechanics of file navigation and then there is the mindset of asking our self, "what am I navigating to".  You do provide a very comprehensive list of approaches.