# how to skip commented lines when navigating?

Tags: key-bindings, navigation

When navigating in normal mode by `j` or `k`, I want to skip commented lines.

Is it possible? Is there a vimscript snippet for that?

Comment: I feel that it is _overly optimistic_  to never use `j`/`k` to navigate/edit a comment. I would recommend upgrading your motion game. See `:h quickref`. Related post: [Quickest navigation within a buffer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2230/778)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I think it would be important that you learn how to move around with motions other than `j` and `k`. Being able to use wide range motions, marks and tags is a good way to avoid comments and move efficiently.

However, you can use the following function and mappings:

```
function! MyVerticalMotions(up)
    " Get the motion to execute based on the parameter
    let motion = a:up ? "k" : "j"

    " Execute the original motion
    execute "normal! " . motion

    " Repeat until we are not on a comment anymore or we reached the end of the buffer
    while synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."),col("."),1)),"name") == "Comment" && line('.') < line('$') && line('.') > 1
        execute "normal! " . motion
    endwhile
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> j :call MyVerticalMotions(0)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> k :call MyVerticalMotions(1)<CR>
```

The function takes one argument indicating if you want to move up or down, it will then repeat `j` or `k` until the current line is not a comment or you reach the top or the bottom of the file.

The mappings simply call the function with the correct parameter. Also, you can still use `gj` and `gk` if you want to move on the comments.

I used [this Wikia post](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Identify_the_syntax_highlighting_group_used_at_the_cursor) to get the syntax group of the current line.

Note that I tested this code quickly on a Vimscript file and a JS file and it seems like it's working but I may have forgotten some edge cases.

Comment: I think you need an extra condition breaking the loop when at the end/beginning of a buffer and you are on a comment line. Else you likely create a endless loop

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt According to my tests it works as is: If I'm on the 3rd line and the first two lines are commented out, I'll do the first `k`, on the second line the loop starts, the highlighting is "Comment" and `line('.') > 1`. So I do `k` again, then the highlighting is still "Comment" but `line('.') == 1` so we don't loop anymore. (And the same is true at the end of the buffer)

Comment: ah, i missed that part in the condition