# I want to improve my cursor movement

Tags: cursor-movement

The thing that slows me down the most when using VIM is getting my cursor to where I want it to be.

How should I practise improving this? Are there tools that teach you movement tricks and force you to navigate efficiently?

Or do I need to force myself? How can I make sure I'm being efficient every time? Maybe there are better ways to get from point A to point B than the best I thought of in that situation, how can I learn them?

Or can anyone recommend general things I should pay attention to to make sure I am moving around efficiently, people have tips and tricks?

Comment: See this question: [Preventing repeated use of hjkl movement keys in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105540/preventing-repeated-use-of-hjkl-movement-keys-in-vim).

Comment: I'm inclined to close this question as too broad, but I'd like the opinion of the other users so I'll let them vote. Now @theonlygusti I think what you really need is to read the full page of [`:h motion.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#motion.txt). The page describes various motions from short range (`hjkl`), to medium range (`}`), to long ranges (tags and jumps). Once you know all of these motions and you use them naturally you'll get much more efficient.

Comment: @statox I want to focus practising them, because I know _of_  them, I am just not used to using them all the time.

Comment: Related post: [Quickest navigation within a buffer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2230/778)

Comment: @statox I think if we can emphasize the question is avout practice techniques, we might be able to narrow in on something... currently i feel like a good answer would be far too long.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Making the question about practice techniques also feels 1) potentially unclear: what is to goal of the practice? What is considered practicing and what is regular Vim use? 2) primarily opinion based: we all have different ways to learn 3) too broad: You can practice with vimtutor, simply by coding everyday, by using vim-adventures and these kind of tools. So the more I think about it, the more I think we should close this question :)

Comment: @statox i leaned that way at first read but couldnt justify. Now i have reasons :)

Comment: @statox i have never heard of "vim-adventures and these kinds of tools", are those going to be useful to me? what are they and how do I find them?

Comment: @theonlygusti Vim-adventures is a [website](https://vim-adventures.com/) which tries to make a platform game based on Vim's motions. Personally I think it is not a great tool because 1) it's not free 2) if you want to practice vim I think you should use vim and not another tool. Still some people recommend it. I think all you really need is to follow `vimtutor`, use vim daily for real development, and maybe read [practical vim](https://pragprog.com/book/dnvim/practical-vim) and see what's available at vimcast.org. But as I said all of that is just a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: So to conclude I will close this question because as I said before it is really too broad and primarily opinion based. I would recommend you to have a look at the subreddit [/r/vim](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim) they have different resources, an interesting wiki an you can ask this kind of questions more than on this site.