# Hardcore vim mode: what is the best way to move vertically?

Tags: normal-mode

This question has been migrated from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576762/hardcore-vim-mode-what-is-the-best-way-to-move-vertically)

I have started using vim a while back and have been jumping with my right hand on and off "home row".  As I learned more about efficient navigation, using "f,t" and "F,T" became my favourite way to navigate within the row, i.e. horizontally.  It is so convenient that i started considering "hardcore vim" mode where the homerow navigation is turned off altogether.

My question is, what would be the high precision vertical navigation approach in "hardcore vim" mode.  Move up one line, move down one line. Few key strokes to position your cursor exactly on a line without knowing or caring about the line number.

Thanks!

P.S. I do know about moving per paragraph, enclosing brackets, but somehow i miss the type of precision that horizontal navigation has.

**After a bit of research:**

[This question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/528/move-vertically-to-a-specific-character-on-a-different-line) seems to be very close to what I am asking.  Although the accepted answer doesn't quite fit the bill for me, it contains a link to [EasyMotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion) plugin, that could help to speed up navigation without using the home row.  Downside being having to install a plugin vs. using raw vim.

Comment: Similar post: [Quickest navigation within a buffer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2230/778)

Comment: Perhaps of interest: my question [how to move vertically until reaching a non-whitespace character](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/120/how-to-move-vertically-until-reaching-a-non-whitespace-character)

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/8-essential-vim-editor-navigation-fundamentals/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use '/' and '?', (forward and backward search) when having to navigate to a line I can see in my buffer. Using a precise enough search I move directly to the wanted position.

Comment: This seems like the way to go indeed

Comment: @ambushed you might also want to `:set incsearch`